# A simple Ruby EmailAddress class

Tags: ruby, regex, validation, email

I wrote this short, plain Ruby lib to handle email address validation inside and outside of Rails applications, and I would like to know what you think.

```
require "i18n"

class EmailAddress
  VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  def self.malformed?(email)
    email !~ VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX
  end

  def self.valid?(email)
    !malformed?(email)
  end

  attr_reader :email, :i18n_scope, :errors

  def initialize(email, i18n_scope: [:models, :email_address])
    @email = email
    @i18n_scope = i18n_scope
    @errors = []
  end

  def valid?
    validate
    errors.empty?
  end

  def validate
    message = I18n.t(:invalid, scope: i18n_scope)
    errors.push(message) if EmailAddress.malformed?(email)
  end
end
```

Usage can be as simple as:

```
if EmailAddress.valid?(params[:email))
  # do something
end
```

Or for remote validations, for example:

```
def email
  email = EmailAddress.new(params[:email])
  if email.valid?
    render nothing: true, status: 200
  else
    render json: { errors: email.errors }, status: 422
  end
end
```

Comment: The absolute most reliable way to test if an email is valid or not is to check the response of `isemail.info/#{emailaddress}`. Unfortunately it doesn't appear that he has a ruby gem for it, so if you have an internet connection then that should be your first choice.

Comment: I might write a gem for that then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Regex will validate some email addresses. Because the Domain Name System [allows UniCode.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_email) the Regex does not match all valid characters in the Doman Name. Therefore it will not validate all valid email addresses.

#### Alternatives:

Validating over all allowable Unicode with Regex in a meaningful way is non-trivial.

1. Sending a confirmation email requiring reply is a straight-forward method for validating email procedurally.
2. When possible, not collecting email addresses at all is easy to implement.